# Simple and Low Resource games for Ubuntu?

Tags: games

I've been helping put together some old computers and installing Edubuntu on them for some newly arriving refugees in AZ. Many of the desktops and laptops are pretty (read: very) low resource, and I'm trying to find some simple (many of these children can't read too complex English yet) and low resource games that would run on these PCs.

So far I've found that these games run great no matter how low specs:

- SuperTux & SuperTux 2
- Frozen Bubbles
- Alienblaster

Anything else??

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest these following additional games for your low-spec computers:

- **Warmux**: A turn based artillery game
- **Pingus**: A Lemmings clone
- **Pysolfc**: 1,000 Solitaire card games (what other games would you need??!)
- **Crack-Attack**: A Tetris clone
- **Xmoto**: A 2d motocross platform game

To install all of these with *a single command* try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install warmux pingus pysolfc crack-attack xmoto
```

I have tested all of these games and they seem entertaining enough and well suited to a low spec computer. Combined with your own suggested games they should give a great experience and a decent 'games pack' :)

Answer (score 2):

### Enigma

Enigma is a fun puzzle game. It doesn't need a lot of power, but be sure to have computer with a *good* mouse installed.

[image: Enigma]

[Enable the "Universe" Repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). And install it with

```
sudo apt-get install enigma
```